# I need to find regex patterns in a string while ignoring spaces in the string to color the output using innerHTML

Tags: html, regex, typescript

I am trying to create a function that takes any regex, finds all occurrences in a string, and color them.

For output style purposes, the string has spaces every 10 characters, but the regex needs to ignore these spaces.

Here is my HTML (I am using samp from bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/code/ for the display font):

`<samp [innerHTML]="highlight(str, pattern)"></samp>`

Here is my Typescript code:

```
public highlight(str: string, pattern: string) {
    let seqWithSpaces = this.insertSpaces(str, true);
    let patternWithSpaces = this.insertSpaces(pattern, false);
    
    return seqWithSpaces.replace(new RegExp(patternWithSpaces, "g"), match => {
            return '<span class="highlightText">' + match + '</span>';
        });
}
    
private insertSpaces(seq: string, isPatternSeq: boolean): string {
    let output: string = "";
        
    if (!isPatternSeq) {
        output = seq.replace(/(.{10})/g,"$1 ")
    } else {
        output = seq.replace(/(.{1})/g,"$1\\s*")
    }

    return output;
}
```

My current code works for any pattern that is just letters/numbers (no regex characters).
For example, when pattern is these types of strings, it works:

- LST
- NSP
- RRSS

The following do not work (not an exhaustive list):

- L[ST]P
- LS.+P
- LS.{2,4}P

I think I have two possible solutions, and I am open to both avenues:

- find a way to format my pattern (which can be anything) to allow for spaces after every character in the output with my current method of displaying the string
- figure out a way to display my formatted string output without using innerHTML so I can find the regex in my string without having to worry about spaces

I attached an image of the output I want in case it is unclear.
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKISG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should try `(l(\s+)?s(\s+)?t)` regex pattern.

For reference, I tested it on https://regex101.com/r/YUmfG5/1